# Compiling Issue using VSC on ONE Simulator

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, one-simulator

I just install ONE Simulator on my pc with updated JDK and JRE 1.8.0_321 using Visual Studio Code text editor. When I compile the main file, here is the problem mentioned:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

```
    Settings cannot be resolved
    DTNSimTextUI cannot be resolved to a type
    Settings cannot be resolved
    DTNSimGUI cannot be resolved to a type

    at core.DTNSim.main(DTNSim.java:83)
```

May I know, what is the problem here and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `DTNSimTextUI` and  `DTNSimGUI` class is not known at compile time. You need to import the related class.

Like this:

```
import package1.package2.DTNSimTextUI
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Buddy..I will try to solve this.

Comment: Here is the updated:

package core;
import gui.DTNSimGUI;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import ui.DTNSimTextUI;

but still, appear this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        Settings cannot be resolved
        DTNSimTextUI cannot be resolved to a type
        Settings cannot be resolved
        DTNSimGUI cannot be resolved to a type